# Windows UWP BluetoothLEDevice caching

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

Cannot find some doc about UWP `BluetoothLEDevice` caching. E.g. for the [`BluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.getgattservicesasync) method. I am interested in:

1. How the result is cached - per `BluetoothLEDevice` instance, per process, some other scope?
2. Does the use of `BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached` parameter refresh the cache? (E.g. `BluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached)`.
3. Is the cache refreshed automatically? E.g. when then the services are not read from device properly first time (a communication error), is the cache is wrong forever, or it refreshed services after some time?
4. How it affects `BluetoothLEDevice.ConnectionStatus`? I have noticed reading cached services keeps `ConnectionStatus` as `Disconnected`. However reading `Uncached` services turns it to `Connected`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. System wide.
2. Yes, we expect the cache to update.
3. A service change notification will cause us to refresh, or reading uncached.
4. Using uncached forces over the air traffic so we will connect, otherwise we only connect when needed. As an example if you are subscribed to a value change notification and the remote device published a directed connectable advertisement we will connect to get the notification. There are many other cases when we connect, but typically only when necessary to save the remote devices battery.

Comment: Recently, the MS doc has been updated: [BluetoothCacheMode Enum Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothcachemode#remarks)